# Redux-> How can I acces my store's objects properties?

Tags: reactjs, redux

At the moment I am learning redux, and I got to the point where I've used the UseState hook to create a list and then I am mapping that list and showing it to the user, after that I added a button that calls a function that adds the objects to the redux store, the thing is that whenever I console log the objects saved they come out as "Object Object", how can I acces them with something like "store.name" and it'd give me the object's name property? And how can I make them come out to the console as something like this:

```
0:
  name: Product01,
  Price: 10$
```

Here's my code:
That is my mapping function:

```
{item.map(product=>
        <div>
            <h1>{product.name}</h1>
            <h2>{product.Price}</h2>
            <button onClick={()=>buyProduct(item)}>Buy</button> 

        </div>)}
```

This is my buyProduct function

```
const buyProduct=(item)=>{
    store.dispatch({type:"buy", payload: item})
  }
```

And this is my redux subscribe:

```
 store.subscribe(()=>{
      console.log('Store is now: ' + store.getState())
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are concatenating the object to a string, the way to see the object in the console would be:

```js
console.log('Store is now: ', store.getState())
```

It is similar but instead of concatenating, you pass a separate argument to `console.log` and let the browser do the concatenation for you.